# Sakurai: Time evolution operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

How does Sakurai derive the infinitesimal time-evolution operator from scratch without Hamiltonian?
$$\mathcal{U}(t_0+dt,t_0) = 1 - i\Omega dt.$$
It is definitely from Taylor's expansion. But complex $i$'s emergence and the sign aren't quite clear here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the axioms of quantum mechanics, we know that time evolution from time $t_0$ up to time $t_1$ is given by a unitary operator $U(t_1,t_0)$. The family of such operators satisfies :
\begin{align}
U(t_2,t_1)U(t_1,t_0) &= U(t_2,t_0)\\
U(t_0,t_0) &= 1 
\end{align}

Now, if $t_1\mapsto U(t_1,t_0)$ is differentiable, since it is unitary, we have :
\begin{align}
U^\dagger(t_1,t_0)U(t_1,t_0) &= 1 \\
\partial_{t_1}U(t_1,t_0)^\dagger|_{t_1=t_0} + \partial_{t_1}U(t_1,t_0)|_{t_1=t_0}& = 0
\end{align}

ie the operator $\partial_{t_1}U(t_1,t_0)|_{t_1=t_0}$ is anti-hermitian. We can therefore write it : $$\partial_{t_1}U(t_1,t_0)|_{t_1=t_0} = -i\Omega(t_0) $$

with $\Omega(t_0)$ hermitian (which turns out to be the Hamiltonian.)

Then, the Taylor expansion gives :
$$U(t_0 + \text{d}t,t_0) = 1 - i\Omega(t_0)\text dt$$

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: Is your 2nd last eqn the only possible way of making the LHS anti hermit Ian

Comment: @Shashaank if $A$ is antihermitian then $B:=iA$ is Hermitian, hence $A=-iB$ where $B$ is Hermitian.